# Getting a random word from a text file

Tags: python, random, indexing, file-io

I am trying to return a word from a text file (so that I can eventually make a game from the word) but right now I get the error

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

this is what my text file looks like

```
yellow
awesome
barking
happy
dancing
laughing
```

and this is the code I currently have

import random

```
def generate_the_word(infile):

    for line in infile.readlines():
        random_line = random.randrange(line[0], line[len(line) + 1])

        print(random_line)



def main():
    infile = open("words.txt","r")
    generate_the_word(infile)

    infile.close


main()
```

Do I have the wrong idea about indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is iterating over every line in the file and indexing into that line. You should also take advantage of Python's [context managers](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Context_Managers), which take care of opening and closing files for you. What you want is to load all the lines:

```
with open(infile) as f:
    contents_of_file = f.read()
```

Your second problem is that you aren't properly indexing into those lines with `randrange`. You want a range between 0 and the max number of lines:

```
lines = contents_of_file.splitlines()
line_number = random.randrange(0, len(lines))
return lines[line_number]
```

You also need to import the `random` module before this will run.

Your whole program would look like:

```
import random

def generate_the_word(infile):
    with open(infile) as f:
        contents_of_file = f.read()
    lines = contents_of_file.splitlines()
    line_number = random.randrange(0, len(lines))
    return lines[line_number]


def main():

    print(generate_the_word("Filename.txt"))


main()
```

You should also note that reading the file every time is inefficient; perhaps read it once and then pick lines from that. You could, for instance, read it in the main function and pass its already-read values to the `generate_the_word` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def generate_the_word(infile):
    random_line = random.choice(open(infile).read().split('\n'))
    return random_line

def main():
    infile = "words.txt"
    print(generate_the_word(infile))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `readlines()`, you get a `list` of lines. The `random` module has a handy method for picking a random element from such iterables which eliminates the need for "manually" dealing with indexing: `random.choice(iterable)`.

All you need is this (no `for` loop necessary):

```
def generate_the_word(infile):
    return random.choice(infile.readlines())

def main():
    infile = open("words.txt","r")
    generate_the_word(infile)

    infile.close

main()
```

To avoid the costly operation of reading the file every time you want a single random word, you could also read the file in `main` and pass the list to `generate_the_word` instead:

```
import random

def generate_the_word(word_list):
    return random.choice(word_list)

def main():
    infile = open("words.txt","r")
    lines = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()
    print generate_the_word(lines)

main()
```

Comment: `infile.close` isn't being called, just looked up. Also, I'd highly suggest using context managers rather than manually opening and closing files. You're also going to end up with `\n` after each line.

Comment: @SilverWingedSeraph Ah, good catch :) I just copied the OP's code and made a few edits. I rarely use explicit `open` and `close` myself but didn't want to change the original code too much so I avoided context managing and newline stripping in this case.